# No disk detected

Tags: boot, bios

**The Problem**

I bought a laptop today (Acer Aspire 5), it came with windows 10.
I am trying to install Centos8, but got a "No disks detected" message.

**What I tried**

3 different distros (centos, gentoo, and pop!_os). None of them can find my ssd. I'm completely unable to format partitions because they don't show up.

From the gentoo bootable usb, I get a shell so I ran `lsblk` and confirmed the only result was the usb stick itself.

I have seen elsewhere that switching to ahci mode might help, but my bios gives no options related to that. Is there perhaps a way to do it outside of bios?

I still have windows installed. I've seen a couple sources talk about setting ahci in regedit, but I don't seem to have the same options.

**Extra notes**

I CAN see all the partitions from windows disk management. Would it help to try deleting everything from there? I don't need a dual boot, windows can be wiped, I just want to be cautious.

Edit 1:

```
> lspci

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9b61 (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics (rev 02)
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Thermal Subsytem
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 02ed
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 02ef
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9462
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Serial IO I2C Host Controller
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Management Engine Interface
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode]
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02b0 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0284
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 02c8
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 02a3
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake SPI (flash) Controller
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

Comment: Add the output of `lspci` to your question so that we know which hardware there is. I guess it is something too new, not yet supported by your Linux kernels. Perhaps there are UEFI settings which make your hardware compatible. Can you put the storage in AHCI mode?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on the acer forum here https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/559754/how-install-a-linux-distro-onto-an-acer-aspire-5-acer-a515-52-776h-with-a-ssd-drive

Turns out you can enable AHCI in the bios, but it's hidden!
For anyone in the future, my steps were:

1. Log into windows
2. Open System Configuration, and enable safe boot
3. Shutdown, open up bios again
4. In the 'main' tab, hit ctrl+s to make the SATA option appear. Then just set it to AHCI